# When the Vue project installs dependencies with yarn, fsevents@1.2.4 appears

Tags: vue.js

项目中用yarn安装依赖一直报fsevents@1.2.4模块不兼容的问题

`info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
error eslint@5.11.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^6.14.0 || ^8.10.0 || >=9.10.0". Got "8.9.1"
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.`

Comment: There is only one error in those logs. Did you try to upgrade Node.js as it tells you to do?

Comment: The `fsevents` thing is just an informative message - it's an Mac-only **optional** dependency. Since you're on Windows, it gets skipped.

Comment: The version of node has been upgraded to the latest version, but it is still not possible. The reload package can be reinstalled through NPM install to run later.

Comment: Open command prompt / powershell and run `node --version` and tell us what version it outputs. If it's anything other than `6.14.x`, `8.10.x` or greater than `9.10.0` then you need to update or downgrade your version of node. The error message implies that you have version `8.9.1` which is incompatible.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the previous dependency packages and reinstall them through NPM install